# What is the Data Catalog service in Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-data-catalog

Does GCP provide a data catalog service like *"Microsoft Azure Data Catalog"*?

If it does not, what are the options for doing data cataloging?

Answer (score 2):

They just announced it a few hours ago - it seems to be in Beta still: https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Data Catalog was announced in Google Cloud Next 19. You can see the session [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qq76r-z_50c&t=407s).

Google Cloud DataCatalog support schematized tags (e.g., Enum, Bool, DateTime) and not just simple text tags and you don't need to define which data will be published you just enabled it and start to use (except for Cloud Storage).

[The Cloud Data Catalog](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/) is in **"beta" today** (May, 1, 2019) and it is working with:

- BigQuery
- Cloud Storage (You must set as indexable creating  a managed
  entry)
- Cloud Pub/Sub

Answer (score -4):

Two closest products that match [MS’s Azure Data Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-catalog/data-catalog-what-is-data-catalog) that I can find from Google Cloud are still in beta:

1. [Google Cloud Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/): a tool to visually explore your data in GCP.  There you can clean and prepare data for analysis. I wouldn’t say that it is a complete replacement though.
2. [Google Data Studio](https://cloud.google.com/data-studio/): it is a GCP’s analog and I think it matches a lot of Data Catalog’s functionality.

Comment: Dataprep along with Trifacta is a data wrangling tool and Data Studio is a visualization tool.

Comment: I didn’t understood what Data Catalog really was. I don’t know of any analogs to it in Google Cloud Platform.